# writing values to a registry key from an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, registry

Trying to write a script that will take a prepolulated array and add those values to a registry key.  The below works, but does not place a comma between the values.

```
$apps = @("whatApp.exe","thatApp.exe","thisAapp.exe")
set-location HKLM:\
foreach($app in $apps){
    set-itemproperty -path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Citrix\wfshell\TWI -Name logoffCheckSysModulestest -Value $apps
}
```

Also, how would i check if these apps were already in that key and to continue to the next value instead of adding it a second time?

Comment: "-Value $apps" should be "-Value $app" without "s".

Comment: @David Brarbant: Made the change, but it only puts the last value of thisApp.exe into the registry key.  Does not concatenate with a comma. Ive tried using -join, but cant get it to work properly as input to -value

Comment: What does it need to look like in the registry? You are overwriting the value with each pass. Does it need to contain all of them? Then you might not need an array. Just maybe a string

Comment: @Matt, it needs to look like whatApp.exe,thatApp.exe,thisApp,exe   comma between each with no trailing comma.

Comment: Just change `$apps = @("whatApp.exe","thatApp.exe","thisAapp.exe")` to `$apps = "whatApp.exe,thatApp.exe,thisAapp.exe"`? Does that work?

Comment: @matt, what works.  do you know how I'd check to see if each item in the $apps string already exists in the reg key, and if so, continue to check the next?  if it does not exist, to add it?

Answer (score 2):

Other ways you could do this but this would be a simple easy to read one.

```powershell
$regPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Citrix\wfshell\TWI"
$regName = "logoffCheckSysModulestest"

$apps = @("whatApp.exe","thatApp.exe","thisAapp.exe")

$values = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regPath | Select -ExpandProperty $regName).Split(",")

$apps | ForEach-Object{
    If($values -notcontains $_){
        $values += $_
    }
}

Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name $regName -Value ($values -join ",")
```

First we take the current value of that keyname in the registry and split it into an array. Then we compare that array with the list of elements in `$apps`. If one of the elements is missing append it to the `$values` arrray.

The `$values` array then should be the updated with all new entries that did not already exist. `-Join` then back together and write the change back to the registry.

In place of the `ForEach-Object` loop you could also use `Compare-Object` to do the work

```powershell
$apps = @("whatApp.exe","thatApp.exe","thisAapp.exe")

$values = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regPath | Select -ExpandProperty $regName).Split(",")

Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name $regName -Value ((Compare-Object $apps $values -IncludeEqual -PassThru) -join ",")
```